# Symfony 3 on Apache server // Postman POST request not working without app.php in url

Tags: php, apache, rest, symfony, postman

I have a working Symfony 3 API on an Apache Server - more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507390/rest-get-with-parameter-ignored-php-symfony-3-mpdf) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598901/post-method-returning-405-method-not-allowed-on-apache-production-server-symfo) these are already resolved

I am now facing a routing problem I think, my postman POST methods working fine if use a URL like: https://example.com/app.php/mcPDF/ but when I try with URL: https://example.com/mcPDF/ it says 404 not found.

I tried several answers here, like changing the htaccess **IfModule mod_rewrite.c>** section and added various settings in 000-default.conf file like:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/pdf/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
```

and every time I do changes I do:

```
- bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
- bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

and I also did the sudo a2enmod rewrite and restarted the server many times

Please advise, let me know what info you need more

Answer (score 0):

All my PROD servers use configuration below and they all work fine. Try to update yours accordingly to see what happens.

```
# $ nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_app/current/web

    <Directory /var/www/my_app/current/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE:** Stage dependent configurations are shown here in details. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/0ew3/deploying-a-symfony-applications-to-staging-and-production-servers-with-capistrano

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it did not work. Please tell me what info you might need so you can help me find the root cause of this problem

Comment: Have you run `a2enmod rewrite` and restared tge apache?

Comment: Also has this `sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php5` before?

Comment: Yes I have Module rewrite already enabled, and when I run the installation of libapache2-mod-php5 it returned **Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate**

Comment: What is your OS? e.g. Ubuntu xxx ?

Comment: Checked the version 7 of the library you suggested since I am working with PHP 7 -  and I found: **libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)**

Comment: From phpinfo():

 - System Linux uvn-243-1.tll07.zonevs.eu 4.4.0-042stab123.9 #1 SMP Thu Jun 29 13:01:59 MSK 2017 x86_64
 - Server API Apache 2.0 Handler
 - Apache Version Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: more info found in the **here** and **here** links I posted at the top

Comment: tried different changes, nothing works .. any help would be appreciated